# Javascript compare 2 object arrays with where conditions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare two object arrays something like

```
list1 = [{id:1,name:'amy'},{id:3,name:'zoe'}];  
list2 = [{id:1,name:'sally'},{id:3,name:'zoe'}];    

select *
from list1 a, list2 b
where a.id = b.id
and a.name = b.name

Result: id:3, name:'zoe'
```

How can I write this in Javascript?

Comment: What are the space and time constraints?

Comment: I suggest to use a custom library, made specifically for such purposes, e.g. [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

Answer (score 5):

You need to loop over both arrays and match values.

```js
list1 = [{id:1,name:'amy'},{id:3,name:'zoe'}];  
list2 = [{id:1,name:'sally'},{id:3,name:'zoe'}];
var r = [];

list1.forEach(function(a){
  return list2.forEach(function(b){
    if(a.id === b.id && a.name === b.name)
      r.push(b)
  })
});
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```js
var list1 = [{id:1,name:'amy'},{id:3,name:'zoe'}];  
var list2 = [{id:1,name:'sally'},{id:3,name:'zoe'}];
var r = list1.filter(x => list2.some(y => x.name == y.name && x.id == y.id))[0];
console.log(r);
```

Comment: where are you comparing `id`s?

Answer (score 1):

You could collect in a hash table all `id` and `name`of `list1` and check later for existence.

```js
var list1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'amy' }, { id: 3, name: 'zoe' }],
    list2 = [{ id: 1, name: 'sally' }, { id: 3, name: 'zoe' }],
    list1hash = Object.create(null),
    result;
       
list1.forEach(function (a) {
    list1hash[[a.id, a.name].join('|')] = a;
});

result = list2.filter(function (a) {
    return list1hash[[a.id, a.name].join('|')];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: why `forEach` instead of `reduce`?

Comment: and it won't work if there is no item with same `id` in the first list, it will throw an error

Comment: becaus `reduce` returns every time the same object.

Comment: `list1id = list1.reduce((acc,item) => { acc[item.id] = item; return acc; }, {})` would work

Answer (score 0):

How about sorting both arrays by id and then iterating concurrently over both of them?

It should result in complexity of `2 * O(n*logn) + n` which is far better than `n^2` as others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Another one (es6):

```js
const list1 = [{id:1,name:'amy'},{id:3,name:'zoe'}];  
const list2 = [{id:1,name:'sally'},{id:3,name:'zoe'}];

const result = list1.reduce((acc, a) => acc.concat(list2.filter(b => a.id === b.id && a.name === b.name)),[]);
console.log('result :', result);
```